# Animate or update view of DragShadowBuilder

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have implemented drag n drop for listview item. which will be draged on `LongPress` . initialy DragShadowBuilder draws bitmap with specified height nd width. But i want to decrement shadow size or apply fade in animation when it arrives to the target. How can i achieve this? how can i trigger that shadow disappear event?

Code on Long click of listview:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            //Selected item is passed as item in dragData
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(month.get(position));

            dragView = v;
            dragView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmapFromView(v);

            String[] clipDescription = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence)v.getTag(),
                    clipDescription,
                    item);
            DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(v,month.get(position),bmp,0);

            v.startDrag(dragData, //ClipData
                    myShadow,  //View.DragShadowBuilder
                    month.get(position),  //Object myLocalState
                    0);    //flags
            commentMsg = v.getTag() + " : onLongClick.\n";
            comments.setText(commentMsg);

            dragView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }};
```

I am creating new `DragShadowBuilder` on action drop event. it goes to my function but it does not updating current shadowBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

It's solved Now. We can not update view of DragShadow. So i just draw image where `ACTION_DROP` fired and applied animation to that imageView.